# Audio fingerprinting system in Java

Tags: java, android, audio-fingerprinting, puid

Are there any audio fingerprinting systems ([PUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Unique_IDentifier), etc) that are implemented in **pure Java** (for running on Android)?

Comment: I have a system that I am working on in Java for doing this, but I don't have the code posted yet. If you're interested e-mail me at kristopher.ives@gmail.com

Comment: Beware that most practical audio finger printing systems are patented,  and require a hefty back end processing system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audio fingerprinting library (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570847/audio-fingerprinting-library-java)

Answer (score 2):

Sony Ericsson has a pure Java audio recognition app, called TrackID, on their new Android phone.  It has also been available on J2ME and presumably other phones for a while. It was developed by Cybercom.

However, it doesn't generate a fingerprint — the audio data is sent to a remote server for identification. As you need to be online anyway to do track identification, I imagine most music recognition apps work in this way.