# Audio fingerprinting library (java)

Tags: java, audio-fingerprinting

Are there any audio fingerprinting libraries **written in Java**? similar to [libofa](http://code.google.com/p/musicip-libofa/) which was written in C++ or C#.

Comment: http://echoprint.me/ is another C++ library.

Answer (score 6):

This open source project called musicg can help you

http://code.google.com/p/musicg/

Comment: I have been thinking about checking this out. Anyone done so already?

Comment: I have recently checked out musicg's `FingerprintSimilarityComputer`. It seems to work well for comparing a full song to a section of itself but doesn't cope (at least out-of-the-box) with noise in one of the recordings.

Answer (score 3):

- See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992161/audio-fingerprinting-system-in-java).
- [phash](http://www.phash.org/) isn't written in java, but has java bindings, so it can be [called from java](http://lists.phash.org/pipermail/phash-support-phash.org/2010-January/000027.html).

> Audio Fingerprinting
>
> Audio fingerprinting permits the identification of unlabelled audio, regardless of the format it is delivered in, or certain signal distortions it may have endured as a result of compression, filtering, transmission, etc. The unknown audio signal is identified via a compact representation of its spectral characteristics that is compared against all records in a reference database. MusicURI makes use of the MPEG-7 standard (formally known as the Multimedia Content Description Interface), which defines a universal mechanism for exchanging multimedia-related descriptive data, and has defined the Audio Signature Description Scheme as its audio fingerprinting tool, for the purpose of robust identification of audio signals.

Comment: do you think one of these could be used successfully with musicbrainz db ? or with freedb

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries for Audio Fingerprinting. Unfortunately most of them are not in Java. Most of them are in C or python. You can search for AcoustID, pHash, jHears, Echoprint.